# How do I remove specific text in a string using substring

Tags: c#, string, substring

**My string is this:**

> fileName, callDateTime, sum(callDuration) AS 'Call Duration',
>   callRecorder, equipmentId, errorMessage, extractionDateTime,
>   interactionId, interrupted, extractionSuccess, stitching, bytes,
>   conversionTime, stitchingTime, transferTime, remoteErrorMessage,
>   remoteTransferDateTime, size, remoteTimeToTransfer,
>   extractionStartDate, extractionEndDate, purpose, ruleName,
>   ruleSession, fileOutputFormat, extractedBy, vaultName, vaultType,
>   vaultRemotePath, stitchingTime

**I want to remove this part of the text:**

> "sum (callDuration) AS 'Call Duration',"

**I am using this piece of code to try to address this problem:**

```
 var getSumIndex = resultAggOrField.IndexOf($"{rowGroup.AggFunc}");
 var getFieldIndex = resultAggOrField.IndexOf($"'{rowGroup.DisplayName}'");
 var delete = resultAggOrField.Substring(getSumIndex, getFieldIndex);
 resultAgg = resultAggOrField.Replace(delete, string.Empty);
```

**But for some reason, he takes this part of the text:**

```
sum(callDuration) AS 'Call Duration', callRec
```

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `rowGroup.AggFunc`?  Of `rowGroup.DisplayName`?  Of `getSumIndex`?  Of `getFieldIndex`?  Of `delete`?  Basically, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: **Result of the delete variable:** `"sum(callDuration) AS 'Call Duration', callRec"`
              I want it to be: `"sum (callDuration) AS 'Call Duration',"`

Answer (score 2):

Your variable names imply that you misunderstand how [the `Substring(int, int)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) works.  The second argument is not an *index*, it's a *length*.

Whether you want to hard-code the length for `"sum (callDuration) AS 'Call Duration',"` or dynamically calculate it (and how you'd dynamically calculate it) is really up to you.  But you need to tell the `Substring()` method the *size* of the substring to remove, not the *ending index* of the substring to remove.